# Matplotlib - Show gridlines and values of a 2D array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I will start out by showing the plot I'm getting:[image]

What I'm trying to do is to have the value of each position to display at the center of each square, that I managed to do, although, it is not visible because I change the map to be binary (black and white). However when I add the grid lines to have them look separated they intersect on top of the values, as shown in the image above.

The array I'm plotting is only 3x3. Therefore, I would like to see nine equal boxes in total with the values at the center of each respective box. Anyone has an idea on how to do this? Here is the piece of my script that does this.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.matshow(np.zeros((3,3)), cmap='binary')
ax.grid(which='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

# To display the values
for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(ipcavg):
    ax.text(j, i, '{:0.2f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center')

plt.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.matshow(np.zeros((3,3)), cmap='binary')
ax.grid(which='major', color='black', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
# To display the values
ax.set_xlim([0,3])
ax.set_ylim([0,3])
for (i, j), z in [[(0,0),0],[(1,1),1],[(2,2),2],[(3,3),3],[(2,3),4],[(1,3),5],[(2,1),6],[(3,2),7],[(1,2),7],[(3,1),8]]:
    ax.text(j-0.5, i-0.5, '{:0.2f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

use set_xlim,set_ylim to draw correctly the boxes
substract from x,y half of box height and provide coordinates for upper rightcorner of box